# How to convert Swift multidimensional Array to Data format for TensorFlow Lite?

Tags: arrays, swift, tensorflow-lite

I have a TFLite model with the following input shape:

```
num_rows = 40
num_columns = 174
num_channels = 1
```

I began with a Swift array, but TensorFlow Lite wants it to be of the type `Data`.

Here is how I tried to convert my array to `Data`:

```
let interpreter = try Interpreter(modelPath: modelPath!)
            
// Allocate memory for the model's input `Tensor`s.
try interpreter.allocateTensors()
            
// Get initial data "sendtoModel" as type Array<Array<Double>>! 
// ... from the testRecognizer() function

let sendtoModel = try? testRecognizer()

// Convert Array<Array>Double>>! to `Data`
let encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: sendtoModel)

// Send converted Data to TFLite model
try self.interpreter.copy(encodedData, toInputAt: 0)
```

When I run this code, I get an error pointing to the last line.

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

What is going on here? I am clearly doing something wrong in the conversion process. I found no null elements in `sendtoModel`, the initial array of double arrays. Then I iterated through the elements of the Data object and checked if any were nil; none were.

I've struggled with this conversion for many hours and would greatly appreciate some pointers. I know there is a way to convert Swift arrays to the `Data` format needed by TFLite for Swift, but my way is not it. I'm not even certain that I'm doing it correctly if I can fix the bug laid out above.

Comment: are you sure it's not crashing on this force unwrap: `modelPath!`, rather than further down?

Comment: @KirilS. Unfortunately, yes. `modelPath!` works fine. If I comment out the last line of code in my question, it runs without errors. Thanks for the suggestion. Any other ideas as to the source of the problem?